# When comparing singular with a plural entities

Tags: grammatical-number

A professor corrected me a sentence in an academic paper and he wrote:

```
An alternative to X method is automatic methods
```

and I am a bit puzzled that you can write a sentence in the form of "[singular entity] is [plural entity]" (or vice versa). Even if this sentence is written in passive form:

```
Automatic methods are an alternative to X method
```

there is still this incongruity that I've mentioned.

What's the correct form?

Comment: First, there is nothing wrong with writing "[singular entity] is [plural entity]". What is wrong is that if there's more than one other possible method, you should use the plural: *"alterntives"*.

Comment: Agree *is* sounds funny. You can fix this by adding *to use one of the*. An alternative to X method is [or *would be*] *to use one of the* automatic methods.

Comment: To add to Phil's comment, "an alternative to X is to use other methods" (without "one of the") is also valid, if the alternative is using multiple methods.

Comment: The verb should conform to the subject.

Comment: 'An alternative to the X method is automatic methods' is not ungrammatical if one accepts wholesale synesis. 'We need to decide what topic we discuss tomorrow morning. An alternative to Timekeeping is Health and Safety.' _However_, how things sound usually trumps [Orwell's VIth Law] all lesser rules of English, and 'An alternative to the X method is automatic methods' sounds pretty awful. 'An alternative to the X method is provided by the automatic methods' is better, but  'Automatic methods are an alternative to the X method' works best....

Comment: 'An alternative' is probably better than countifying to 'alternatives'; 'An alternative to the X method is provided by the automatic methods' sounds better than 'Alternatives to the X method are provided by the automatic methods'; it is a deletion of  say  'A set of approaches differing from the X method is provided by the automatic methods'